# regex expression for any letter, number and "normal" characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I receive bytes into a method and I want to send them over serial, but I only want to send valid bytes, (i.e. a-zA-Z0-9"!£$%^&*()-_=+), things like that, spaces, new lines etc. I just want to filter out any character like ones with accents or �, in any order and any number of times.

Would something like this including all characters with `|` work?

```
^[a-z|A-Z|0-9|\\s|-<other characters>]*
```

Or, what would be the correct expression?

So if a string contained "exit����", I would only want to send "exit", and never send characters that are not valid, but send everything else.

```
public void write(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count) {
  String str;
  try {
    str = new String(bytes, "ASCII");
    Log.d(TAG, "data received in write: " +str );
    //^[a-z|A-Z|0-9|\s|-]*
    //test here, call next line on any character that is valid
    GraphicsTerminalActivity.sendOverSerial(str.getBytes("ASCII"));
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "exception" );
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  // appendToEmulator(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

EDIT: I tried [^\x00-\x7F] which is the range of ascii characters....but then the  � symbols still get through, weird.

Comment: You want to replace all invalid or do you want to check that the string doesn't contain invalid?

Comment: If the string contains invalid characters I don't want them in the string that is sent. I only want the string to contain valid characters. So i receive abc�, I want the string to be abc instead.

Comment: you need to start by defining "valid byte"

Comment: and you need to read a documentation about regex, as neither `^`, `|` nor `[]` seem clear to you

Comment: bad terminology, I just want to send any character that I mentioned, and if it is not one of those characters strip it from the string. I suppose I could test teh string and make a new string with any of the valid characters founc

Answer (score 3):

Try using pattern like `[\x20-\x7E]` These are the ASCII codes of [the printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

By the way I assume you are asking about ASCII, because this is how you parse in your question.

Comment: looks good, but it seems there are also things like "spaces, new lines etc." (i'm not going to try and guess what that can mean)

Comment: That looks good. Well the data received can have whitespace, \n or \r

Comment: @njzk2 Space fit into the range I provide. All others - I assuem the user ask about printable characters.

Comment: @Paul for \n or \r you will need to add two more characters to the pattern - either with byte codes or with special symbols.

Comment: Thanks boris, this looks good, will have  a look at incorporating it.

Comment: I tried [^\\x00-\\x7F] which is the range of ascii characters....but then the  � symbols still get through. I don't understand.

Comment: @Paul Read my link through you willl see qiute a lot of the ascii characters are not displayal ones. Also ASCII characters are easily refer to `\p{ASCII}`

Comment: but which non displayable ones would come up as �? It seems I only want some of the on-displayable ones to remain and to remove others so. I want to keep \b, \r \n but not whatever is causing � to appear. I'll look over your link again thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a search-replace:

```
String fixed = input.replaceAll("[^\p{Print}\t\n]", "");
```

Rolf

Edit: Add references:

[Pattern Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) -> scroll down to POSIX Character Classes (US-ASCII ONLY)

The pattern above matches all characters that are *not* printable characters....

Comment: thanks, I will have to refresh my regex to understand this, as @njzk2 said

Comment: That's really good, how do you add in an exception to allow \r and \n ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Java's [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class if you haven't already.  It would allow you to extract the "normal" character from its accented equivalent, as an alternative to throwing away the whole character.

I don't remember my exact source for this idea (I was trying to do accent-agnostic searching recently), but a quick search turned up [this simple blog post](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2009/10/how-to-strip-accents-from-strings-using-java-6/) that may offer a little more insight into how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe is **not** the correct way to turn your list of characters into a regular expression.     Put the characters in a charecter class with square brackets around it.  All characters in the character class are by default ORed, so no need for pipes.  There is a need to escape symbols that are not numbers and letters.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\"\!\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\=\+]
```

And then if you want to put that into a Java string, you need to double escape the escapes

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\\"\\!\\£\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\_\\=\\+]");
```

Keep in mind that the pound symbol (£) is **not** an ASCII character, so converting it to ASCII is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this, I actually don't need any non ascii character apart from I wish to leave \r and \n intact. Don't need £.